# CSS - Parent div extends beyond child SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an SVG that I'm using in the header for a logo. Lots of flex boxes. Something like...

*HTML*

```
<header id="header">

    ... stuff ...

    <div class="logo">
        <svg class="logo-color">
            <title>Title</title>
            <use xlink:href="/images/svgs.svg#logo-color-bt"></use>
        </svg>
    </div> <!-- /.logo -->

    ... stuff ...

</header> <!-- /#header -->
```

*CSS (SASS)*

```
#header {

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

    align-items: center;

    height: 50px;

    ... other css...

    .logo {
        flex: 1;

        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;

        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;

        svg.logo-color {
            display: block;
            height: 32px;

            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }
}
```

Everything displays well, and I can change the SVG size to anything I want. BUT! When I hover the mouse over the logo, the cursor still appears as `cursor` far outside of the SVG (but not the entirety of the `.logo` div).

The entire `.logo` div (green rectangle is SVG)...

[image: Entire logo div]

The `svg.logo-color` element...

[image: svg.logo-color element]

The SVG...

[image: SVG element]

The second screenshot shows the area that the cursor appears as `pointer`.

What I'd like is to have `svg.logo-color` fit to the SVG drawn within. The issue is that the height (and therefore the width) of the SVG image may change, and so I cannot put in a hard-coded value for the width.

Please let me know if anything is unclear. To boil it down: I only want the `pointer` cursor within the green rectangle, and just a regular arrow otherwise.

**EDIT #1 - (Additional Info)**

As MullerA cleverly pointed out, I can set `cursor: pointer;` to only the `use` element. But when the page is resized smaller, the unwanted *"padding"* causes some flow issues. I'd like to get rid of it all together, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SVG is using the default width of "300px" because you aren't giving it any other idea of what it should be.

If you want it to be the same size as the logo, then give your inline SVG (ie. `svg.logo-color`) an appropriate `viewBox` attribute.

You don't include your other SVG file.  So we have no isea what the element `#logo-color-bt` is.  If it is a `<symbol>`, then should just be able to use its `viewBox`.

Comment: Yep, that did it. The external file has `viewBox` in the `<symbol>` tag, but adding it to the HTML in the `<svg>` tag did the trick. It would be nice to not have to include it in the HTML, but the result is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Comment: An odd side-effect is that resizing the window is much smoother now, having added the `viewBox` attributes to the HTML `<svg>` tags. Before it was very choppy and laggy, but now it's quite nice. Maybe a result of other changes made, but I don't think I've done anything else since then.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `cursor: pointer` only to your `use` element.

Comment: Clever, I didn't think of that. It might work, but the design is responsive, and when the header width gets small enough, the unwanted *"padding"* causes flow issues. I reckon your solution would work for the cursor issue, but not the latter (which, granted, I did not really mention in the question).

Comment: You can set the width of the `use` element to 100% so it can span the whole width of the parent div eliminating any padding; but this would add extra width.

Comment: Interesting development... I set `svg.logo-color` to `width: 100%;`, and that works very well. BUT! When I set `use` to have `cursor: pointer;`, it *only* displays the pointer above filled parts of the SVG. Any holes or transparent parts - even in the middle of the SVG - go back to the default arrow. The logo is predominantly (entirely) text, so this is an issue. Nice try though!